# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str. and how to convert dataframe list to int

Tags: python, list, types

I'm fetching an historical data in data frame and its contain in a list format. whenever I use these data to make an indicator I get this error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str.
```

Do I need to change my data frame type into int, if its yes then how to do these?

```
records= api.get_time_price_series(exchange='NSE', token='22', starttime=23.6528752, 
interval=5)#historical data

df=pd.DataFrame(records)

into=df['into'].values
inth=df['inth'].values
intl=df['intl'].values
intc=df['intc'].values
# print(df)
def levels (records):
    """retuns pivote points support/reistance levels """
     inth=round(records['inth'][1],2)
     intl=round(records['intl'][1],2)
     intc=round(records['intc'][1],2)
     pivot=round((inth+intl+intc)/3,2)
     r1 = round((2*pivot-intl),2)
     r2 = round((pivot+(inth-intl)),2)
     r3 = round((inth + 2 *(pivot-intl)),2)
     s1 = round((2*pivot-inth),2)
     s2 = round((pivot-(inth-intl)),2)
     s3 = round((intl - 2 *(inth-pivot)),2)
return(pivot,r1,r2,r3,s1,s2,s3)

pp_levels=levels(records)
print(pp_levels)
```

Comment: please provide a **reproducible** example, what if the initial `df` or `records`?

Comment: I think your first field in some records are not integer and you assuming them as index. Try to find them in `try except` or define a new counter and set it as index and first field of dataframe records will shift one position right in this situation.

Comment: i uploaded the output of records in above image

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Actually I got the issue right now ,   when I print (records ) it has to return in Data Frame but some where its changing to list . so. how can I change  list object in  Data Frame ?